# Sockets - IPEndpoint Port (Max Value)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

What is the max value of the port i can assign on my socket when i do a bind?

Example:

```
int port = 0; //How far can i go?
Socket m_mainSocket;
m_mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IP port numbers are 16-bit unsigned integers. Therefore 65,535 is the maximum port number you can assign.

The documentation for the `IPEndPoint` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k17zbw22.aspx) states that an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will be raised if the port is greater than [`MaxPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.maxport.aspx). The documentation for `MaxPort` states that 'the MaxPort value is set to `0x0000FFFF`' (65,535).

Comment: Note that a lot of ports - especially in the higher number range - are reserved for use as [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) and *should* not be bound to.

Answer (score 0):

The IPEndpoint class has a `MaxPort` and a `MinPort` field - according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.maxport.aspx):

> The MaxPort value is set to
>   0x0000FFFF.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically access the maximum allowed value, you can use 
    IPEndPoint.MaxPort
and
    IPEndPoint.MinPort
for the minimum value. These are useful for checking that a port that the user input is within the proper bounds before actually trying to use it in a connection.